# Recording multiple key presses in x11

Tags: c, keyboard, x11

I want to record simultaneous key presses and test a function in x11 using C. For example, I was able to set something like,
if 'Q' is pressed, 
   let the window resize.

But I could not find a method for doing the same with a key combination such as Ctrl+Enter, etc, so that when 'Ctrl+Enter' is pressed, the window resizes.

Is there any event type or mask or function in x11 for recording these simultaneous key events ?

The code below is what I have written so far for recording single keys and performing specified action.

```
// USES KEYBOARD KEY TO RESIZE A WINDOW

// Compile : gcc -o go key_and_win.c -lX11

#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    Display *d;
    Window window;
    XEvent event, ev;
    int s;

    /* open connection with the server */
    d = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (d == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open d\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    s = DefaultScreen(d);

    /* create window */
    window = XCreateSimpleWindow(d, RootWindow(d, s), 10, 10, 200, 200, 1,
                           BlackPixel(d, s), BlackPixel(d, s));

    /* select kind of events we are interested in */
    XSelectInput(d, window, StructureNotifyMask | ExposureMask | KeyPressMask | KeyReleaseMask );

    /* map (show) the window */
    XMapWindow(d, window);

    /* event loop */
    while (1)
    {
        XNextEvent(d, &event);

        /* keyboard events */
        if (event.type == KeyPress)
        {
            printf( "KeyPress: %x\n", event.xkey.keycode );         

            if(event.xkey.keycode == 0x18)      // Resize on pressing Q as, key Q => 0x18
            {
                printf("Here in Q\n");

                int r = XResizeWindow(d, window, 100, 200);     // Resizing the window through Q keypress
                if(r==BadValue || r==BadWindow)
                    printf("Error in resizing\n");

                XNextEvent(d, &event);                          // To get ConfigureNotify event
                if(event.type == ConfigureNotify)
                    printf("Resized!\n");
                else
                    printf("Not resized\n");
                //XMapWindow(d, window);                            // Map the resized window   (not necessary)
            }
            /* exit on ESC key press */
            if ( event.xkey.keycode == 0x09 )
                break;
        }
    }

    /* close connection to server */
    XCloseDisplay(d);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to look at `event.xkey.state`

from [10.5.2 Keyboard and Pointer Events](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/keyboard-pointer/keyboard-pointer.html#XKeyEvent) : 
The state member is set to indicate the logical state of the pointer buttons and modifier keys just prior to the event, which is the bitwise inclusive OR of one or more of the button or modifier key masks: Button1Mask, Button2Mask, Button3Mask, Button4Mask, Button5Mask, **ShiftMask**, **LockMask**, **ControlMask**, Mod1Mask, Mod2Mask, Mod3Mask, Mod4Mask, and Mod5Mask.

Comment: Hi. I tried with the event.xkey.state member, and found that when I pressed Ctrl+Shift+Enter, the state becomes 21. If only Ctrl+Enter is pressed, state is 20. But I also found that pressing Ctrl+Shift+X (X can be any alphabet key) also gives 21. So, how can I specify Ctrl+Shift+Enter to be the combination that activates the resize function ?

Comment: I just replaced the if's condition with `event.xkey.state == 21` to get the job done, but that doesn't make it a unique key combination. So any possibility to do that

Comment: The _state_ manages *only* the buttons and modifiers (shift, control ...) this is why whatever the key Ctrl+Shift gives 21. The key is given by _keycode_, you need to look both at _keycode_ and _state_

Comment: you can combinate them with `event.key.state * 256 + event.xkey.keycode` (more than 256 if _keycode_ can be greater 255 of course, sorry I don't remember the possible values right now)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That combination saved a lot. I found out the `unsigned int` keycode of Ctrl, Shift and Enter. The `state` at the pressing of Ctrl+Shift+Enter was 21. And the last pressed key (Enter here) had keycode 36. So using your trick, I set the condition to `if(event.key.state * 256 + event.xkey.keycode == 21*256 + 36)` , and this worked only when the desired key was pressed.